# URL of static data in Grails

Tags: grails

I wrote a Grails project which does speech processing and produces several speech files. I saved the files in a folder in the root of the project for example:

```
..\\MapCloudWebServices\\speechdata\\123456.wav
```

When I run-app everything is working correctly and all the files are produced and saved in the the mention folder (speechdata). But we I run URL from the browser (`localhost:8080/MapCloudWebServices/speechdata/123456.wav`) I got the error message (http 404)  that the requested resource is not available! 
Could anybody help me how to assign the data in Grails project folders to appropriate URL on server? (maybe in config file?)

Thanks,
Reza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your static content such as your wav files under the `web-app` directory of your grails project.